# How to change the bibliography style (nature) in TeXstudio (+ MiKTeX, biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texstudio

In Overleaf I use

```
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
```

in the preamble and

```
\printbibliography
```

in the document. The result is
[image]

[image]

**I want to do the same in TeXstudio but I can't. Can you help me?**

Comment: Overleaf manages most of the compilation steps for you automatically behind the scenes. If you want to compile your document locally you need to compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with setting your editor up for Biber.

Comment: Any new here? Did you manage to run Biber in TeXstudio? Do you get the desired output now? If not, what did you try and how does it nor work for you?

Comment: I already posted my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

1) I installed the "nature" and "biblatex-nature" packages in the MiKTeX console:

[image]

2) In the TeXstudio preferences (Options / Configure TeXstudio), I chose the Build tab and changed the 'Default Bibliography Tool' to 'Biber':

[image]

3) Finally I compiled as follows:

1. (F5) PdfLaTeX or LaTeX
2. (F8) Biber
3. (F5) PdfLaTeX or LaTeX

The result is:

[image]
[image]